# Bash assignment variable in for loop returns "command not found"

Tags: bash, shell-script

In Bash, I want to:

1. Create 3 variables with name ID1, ID2, ID3
2. Variables will be assigned string values ID1_VALUE, ID2_VALUE and ID3_VALUE respectively

I created a for loop like this

```
for ID_COUNT in 1 2 3; do
    ID${ID_COUNT}=ID${ID_COUNT}_VALUE;
done;
```

When the snippet is run, I got this

```
ID1=ID1_VALUE: command not found
ID2=ID2_VALUE: command not found
ID3=ID3_VALUE: command not found
```

and the value ID1, ID2, ID3 are all not set (`set | grep ID1` shows nothing).

Could anyone please explain in details what happened?

Comment: You need `do export ID${ID_COUNT}=ID${ID_COUNT}_VALUE;`

Comment: Thanks for your response. But can you explain why I need to do that? I thought the `export` command is used for making a variable in a the current shell available in its sub-shell. This for loop doesn't run in a sub shell. Even if it does, export wouldn't make it visible in the parent shell (which is the current shell).

Comment: The export command is used to set a variable. Try this for example: `export ID1=ID1_VALUE` and then `echo $ID1` and you'll get `ID1_VALUE` as the output. You are getting an error because you are telling to run `ID1=ID1_VALUE` (as well as the others) as a command after `do` which doesn't work because those aren't commands. With `export` in place, there is a command to be executed and the value will be assigned to the variable which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the purpose of the `export` command. It makes more sense now. However, you said running `ID1=ID1_VALUE` as a command after `do` doesn't work because it isn't a command. I tried an example: `for A in 1 2 3; do B=$A; done;` and then `echo $B` gives 3. I don't understand the difference between the 2 scripts. I notice that the only difference is the parameter expansion on the left in the assignment `ID${ID_COUNT}` and it is causing the problem. Can you please explain why?

Comment: In your second example, you are assigning the value of `$A` to `B`. In your question, it is being interpreted as one long command because that isn't being done. Try using `export` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @TranTriet You were correct about `export`, and Nasir is not.

Comment: @NasirRiley Please post answers as answers, not comments, so that they can be voted on.

Comment: @Michael Homer What I said about export is correct and the example that I've given does what I said. If you have other information then please enlighten us.

Comment: @NasirRiley Notwithstanding whether it's correct or not, please post it as an answer 

Comment: @NasirRiley I tried the `export`: `export ID${ID_COUNT}=ID${ID_COUNT}_VALUE;` and it worked so thanks for that. However, I want to understand why I need to use export there, and not in the second example. You said "In your second example, you are assigning the value of $A to B. In your question, it is being interpreted as one long command because that isn't being done" which I don't quite understand. First, in my question, I'm also just assigning the value of  `ID${ID_COUNT}_VALUE` to the variable ` ID${ID_COUNT}`, why is it interpreted as a *long command*. And what is a long command?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `bash` is particular about the interpretation of a command line, where it discovers variable assignments before evaluating used variables. Basically a variable assignment requires the name part to be a proper name, and not one derived by evaluation. But there is the notion of "nameref", where a variable has a variable name as a value, and then the assignment to it instead becomes an assignment to the variable named by its value. It would look something like the following in your example:

```
for ID_COUNT in 1 2 3; do
    declare -n X=ID${ID_COUNT}
    X=ID${ID_COUNT}_VALUE;
done;
```

The same thing is of course achieved with the `eval` command, which evaluates its arguments as a command within its calling context. Using that would look as follows:

```
for ID_COUNT in 1 2 3; do
    eval ID${ID_COUNT}=ID${ID_COUNT}_VALUE;
done;
```

As noted, using `export` has the similar effect, with the addition of making the variable exported to sub processes, which is its primary function.

Comment: `declare $x=y` would be another option preferable to `export`, and also to `eval` if there's any doubt about the values involved.

Comment: `eval`  was the solution for my problem of using aliases in a `for` loop on the command-line. The aliases were correctly defined in the loop, but still couldn't be used directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your scripts, current and future, would be better if you used an array for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3; do
    id[i]="ID${i}_VALUE"
done

echo 'contents of the array "id":'
printf '\t%s\n' "${id[@]}"
```

The output of this script would be

```
contents of the array "id":
        ID1_VALUE
        ID2_VALUE
        ID3_VALUE
```

The loop in the script could also be replaced by

```
id=( "ID"{1..3}"_VALUE" )
```

which uses a brace expansion to create the array.

---

What happens in your code is that the variable `$ID_COUNT` in `ID${ID_COUNT}=ID${ID_COUNT}_VALUE;` is expanded yielding `ID2=ID2_VALUE` if its value is 2.  At that point in executing the command, however, variables have already been detected, so what you have now is a *string* with an equals sign in it.  The shell will go on to try to execute this string as if it was the name of a command.